# How to create a dynamic url for radsocialshare facebook button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, telerik, rad

How to create a dynamic url for radsocialshare facebook button?

i have a radsocialshare facebook like button in radgrid items i want when i click on like button of radgrid item the item url will be share in facebook as ~/page.aspx?id=1

Note : ID will be auto generated according to the radgrid items

Answer (score 0):

Either bind the control's [UrlToShare](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/socialshare-controlling-posts-content-and-title.html) property (e.g. in the ItemDataBound event) which is easier, or [set it on the client](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/socialshare-client-side-change-shared-strings.html) (in this case you cannot use ~/ for the root, you need a client-usable URL) if you have only one instance above/below the grid.

Answer (score 0):

In the radgrid's ItemCreated event, you can set the UrlToShare property like so:

```
    Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemCreated
        Dim RadSocialShare1 As RadSocialShare = e.Item.FindControl("RadSocialShare1")
        If RadSocialShare1 IsNot Nothing Then
            'In this example, "ID" is a field in the data bound to the radgrid
            Dim myID as string = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ID")

            'Now Make the Url
            Dim myUrl as string = "~/page.aspx?id=" & myID

            RadSocialShare1.UrlToShare = myUrl
        End If
    End Sub
```